# Intergrating haystack into my application

Tags: django, django-haystack

I have written a custom platform for display products (like ecommerce with no carts and shipping)

Anywway, I have haystack up and running at 127.0.0.1/myapp/search, I can perform searches, the results return perfectly and all works as it should.

here is my working urls

http://dpaste.com/698413/

And currently my search file, which redirects to an empty base.html (with the content block)

http://dpaste.com/698414/

Now as you can see via my urls.py file, my products are loaded via a custom url + view entry.

This redirects me to a template called detail.html, which contains (you guessed it) detailed information according to what product has been loaded.

Now when I try and include my search.html file into my detail.html (the same one used with my /search entry) the code doesnt render correctly, it shows the form method, but nothing else.

What I am asking is, how can I get my haystack search code to load in my detail.html page.

Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do. What do you mean by "include my search.html file into my detail.html"? Are you wanting a search form on that page, the actual search results, or something completely different?

Comment: Include as in incldue the the file into my template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing that `form` context variable is not set when `details.html` template is rendered. Override DetailView and set extra context data for form should make form to appear on page, something like this:

```
from haystack.forms import SearchForm

#in overriden DetailView
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    #call super
    ctx['form'] = SearchForm() 
    return ctx
```

Comment: Sort of, I wasnt including anything in my view, this code isnt correct, but pointed me to the right place in the haystack docs.